# How do I prevent SSRS graph images from timing out (stream not found error)?

Tags: image, reporting-services, outlook, timeout

I have an issue whereby SQL Server Reporting Services graph image URLs become unavailable after attempting to just request the images after a few minutes (instead of also refreshing the HTML).

The actual error is:
"The stream cannot be found. The stream identifier that is provided to an operation
cannot be located in the report server database. (rsStreamNotFound)"

Assuming the images are timing out, is there any way to extend this timeout value?

The environment is finicky and not ideal, but cannot be changed at this time. The report is being generated through an ASP.NET application (which makes a web service call and populates an ASP.NET literal control) and rendered in the "Outlook Today" page in Outlook 2000. See diagram, below:

http://paulw.us/blog/uploads/outlooktoday.GIF

The Reporting Services is running 2008, but the data comes from a SQL Server 2005 database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's apparently no way to do this, from what I've found. The workaround that I've implemented is to turn on caching and run a data-driven subscription to generate the report. There are some problems with this, namely that it doesn't always seem to prevent the user from having to reload the report.

A more robust way is to enable history and a batch process that changes default parameters and creates the report, cycling through everything like in a data-driven subscription, but maintaining external references to which report goes with which date and history ID. For instance, you could have a database table that tracks the report run time, report ID and parameter set, and query against it to know which to display based on your parameters.